# Issue related to Static keyword in Object Oriented Programming

Tags: c#, .net, static

I have the following class:

```
 public abstract class TMSPageBaseClass : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
     protected DevExpress.Xpo.Session XpoSession;
 }

 public class CommonUtility : TMSPageBaseClass
 {
    protected static t_rolepermissions GetPermissions()
    {
       //here I want to access the variable XpoSession defined in abstract class, I tried
       this.XpoSession  //it throws an error saying: Keyword this is not valid in a static Property,
      }
 }
```

So how can I access that inherited class variable into a static function?

Comment: Why does GetPermissions() have to be static?

Comment: Please do **not** tag with languages that are not correct. This is not C or C++.

Comment: That's right, you cannot access instance members from static methods. Why did you make your method `static` in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Static properties or methods can not refer to the current instance (this) because they are not defined on instance level but on class level.

They should either refer to only static members or get an object passed in that they can refer to (instead of this).

Answer (score 0):

Make the method non-static or pass in a `CommonUtility` as a parameter. Static methods can't access instance variables because static methods don't have an instance to reference.

Answer (score 0):

**As a rule of thumb: Non-static members can't be accessed from static members.**

> how can i access that inherited classe's variable into static function?

1. Create an instance within static method.
2. Access property directly using object OR call an instance method.
3. Within method use non-static property.

However you should change signature from

```
protected static t_rolepermissions GetPermissions()
```

to

```
protected t_rolepermissions GetPermissions()
```

Another point came to mind, a little late though, it doesn't make sense to mark a member both `static` and `protected`. static won't be inherited so marking it protected doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can do that. If you want to access your variable in a static method, than that variable must also be static.

Otherwise you could also pass an instance of your object to your static method. Something like:

```
public class CommonUtility : TMSPageBaseClass
{
    protected static t_rolepermissions GetPermissions(TMSPageBaseClass context)
    {
       context.XpoSession;
    }
}
```